# PIVOT Statement in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

In db **Microsoft SQL Server 2005** I execute this query:

```
SELECT
 doRegion,
 YEAR (doDate) AS 'doYear',
 COUNT (*) AS 'doNumber'
FROM
    [dbo].[doTable]
GROUP BY
    doRegion,
    YEAR (doDate)
ORDER BY
    doRegion,
    YEAR (doDate) DESC;
```

And I have this output:

```
+----------+------+--------+
|doRegion  |doYear|doNumber|
+----------+------+--------+
|northw    |2017  |806     |
|northw    |2016  |186     |
|northw    |2015  |149     |
|northw    |2014  |114     |
|northw    |2013  |72      |
+----------+------+--------+
```

I need instead this output :

```
+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+
|doRegion   |2017|2016|2015|2014|2013|
+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+
|northw     |806 |186 |149 |114 |72  |
+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I think have to use it **PIVOT** syntax and I have tried this [tutorial](http://www.tsqltutorials.com/pivot.php) without success.

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Comment: what did you try and which error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Dynamic Sql

Sample Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t
;With cte(doRegion  ,doYear,doNumber)
AS
(
SELECT 'northw'    ,2017  ,806 UNION ALL    
SELECT 'northw'    ,2016  ,186 UNION ALL    
SELECT 'northw'    ,2015  ,149 UNION ALL    
SELECT 'northw'    ,2014  ,114 UNION ALL     
SELECT 'northw'    ,2013  ,72    
)
SELECT * INTO #t FROM cte
```

Dynamic Sql

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max),@COlumnName nvarchar(max)

SELECT @COlumnName=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME(doYear) FROM #t i
ORDER BY i.doYear DESC FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @COlumnName

SET @Sql='SELECT doRegion,'+@COlumnName+ 'FROM
         (
         SELECT * FROM #t
         )AS SRC
         PIVOT
         (
         MAX(doNumber) FOR doYear IN ('+@COlumnName+')
         )AS Pvt
'
Print @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Result

```
 doRegion   2017    2016    2015    2014    2013
------------------------------------------------
northw       806    186      149     114     72
```